# Enable DCOM via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, registry, dcom

I want to enable **DCOM** using *VBScript*.
It is possible to enable **DCOM** like [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771387.aspx), but I am searching for a way to do this via *VBS*.
Is this possible ? May with *RegKeys* ...?

Answer (score 0):

The registry value that is related to the "Enable Distributed COM on this Computer" setting is in the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\OLE" key. It is an REG_SZ value called EnableDCOM. It is set to Y to enable and N to disable DCOM. Is this what you need or do you also need a code sample showing how to change these registry keys via VBS? Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/825750